# Can't access site after making changes to the functions.php

Tags: php, functions

I was editing the function.php in my site when my whole site went down. I can't even get into the dashboard or login. Any attempt to go to the site results in this message:

"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

I have not gotten any email. I looked online and all the solutions say to go to the dashboard to do something but I can't access the dashboard. One solution said to use FileZilla to access the site but researching more it seems that that had to be set up in the dashboard previously to get the username to access it, something I can't do.

I don't have access to the host of the site as I'm not the host owner.

Is there any solutions or way to load into the site in a safe mode?

Comment: You will need to go through the host. You need some access to the files of the website.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to hosting? Any control panel like cpanel or anything else? Or any access to ftp? if yes the head over there and to got `wp-content/themes/` and rename your current theme folder. Doing that will automatically load a fallback theme. That way your website will be live again immediately and you can continue debugging the issue. Also I suggest to enable debug mode in `wp-config.php` to get a better idea of the reason behind the error.

Comment: I don't have access to the cpanel as "I'm not the host owner."